# Cylinder as trivial fiber bundle with fiber $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

In prepartion for the example of a Mobius strip, a cylinder is often taken as a first example of a trivial fiber bundle with fiber $I$ and total space $S^1\times I$. However, it seems to me that we can also look at a cylinder as a fiber bundle with fiber $S^1$ parametrized by $I$. Is this incorrect?

Comment: That is correct. What are you asking?

Comment: You can always look at any product $M\times N$ is a fiber bundle with fiber either $M$ or $N$